# Maven archetype: Reference artifactId in markdown site files

Tags: maven, markdown, maven-archetype, maven-site-plugin

I am creating a maven archetype. It should contain some predefined files in
`src/site/markdown`. These files should include the artifactId.

I tried to reference it using `${artifactId}` inside the md file but no luck.

Any other idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the respective fileset in the `archetype-metadata.xml` one need to set `filtered=true`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and this is how I fixed it.

In the `resources/META-INF/maven/archetype-metadata.xml`, I added

```
<fileSet encoding="UTF-8" filtered="true">
  <directory></directory>
  <includes>
    <include>README.md</include>
  </includes>
</fileSet>
```

Then in the `resources/archetype-resources/README.md` I added

`The name of the project is ${artifactId}`

Now when I build a maven project using this archetype, I have the value of `artifactId` populated in the `README.md` file.

Comment: How does this differ from my answer?